# How to change colour of Navigation Bar in Beamer

Tags: beamer, color

Does any one know how to change  colour of  Navigation Bar in  Beamer.

I have used  the following in preamble

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
 %\usetheme{Madrid}
 %  \usetheme{Warburg}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[section]
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
%\usepackage{cooltooltips}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
Text Here
\end{document}
```

And  got out put as [image]

I have realised that changing theme will change colour. But i would like to know is it possible to change yellow color in picture as magenta color with same theme as warsaw. so that slide in blue-magenta combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is try to modify the color scheme you used. First of all, find it. In Linux you do something like:

```
[romano:~] % locate wolverine
/usr/share/texmf/doc/latex/beamer/beamerugcolorthemewolverine.pdf
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemewolverine.sty
```

...and you now know that the `wolverine` color style is defined in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemewolverine.sty`.

So you look at this file and you'll find all the color definitions. Copy them on your document (after calling the colortheme). I then substituted all the ocurrences of `yellow` to `magenta`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    %\usetheme{Madrid}
    %  \usetheme{Warburg}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \usecolortheme{wolverine}
    \definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.8}

    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=darkblue!80!magenta}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=darkblue!60!black,bg=magenta!85!orange}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=darkblue!70!black,bg=magenta!60!orange}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=darkblue!80!black,fg=magenta!50!orange}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=darkblue,bg=magenta!20!orange}

    \setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{fg=darkblue,bg=orange!75!white}

    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{fg=darkblue!10!black}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{fg=darkblue!50!black}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=magenta!10!orange}

    \setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=magenta!90!orange}
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=magenta!60!orange}

    \setbeamercolor*{separation line}{}
    \setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[section]
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
%\usepackage{cooltooltips}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{New frame}
    Example text 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

...and:

[image: Output from the code above]

(ouch!) ...this is quite painful. But yes, you have to adjust it bit by bit, probably.

A very helpful document is the [beamer appearance cheat sheet](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf) that can guide you through the adjustable things in your presentation.