# Modifying colors of beamer theme Madrid: Title, footer author box and Dates and Slides

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I writing a latex presentation using madrid and beaver theme. I want to change the color of the Title of the Presentation, Background box of the institute, font color of footer title, page number and date to HTML color code `#00a1e5`. The changes are marked in Figure below. [image]. Here motivation is the frame title.

Changing the color theme to beetle or any other is not what I want as I want the gray background behind title, frame title, dates, footer title to remain the same gray. Here is the basic working code. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{The title}
\author[The author]{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{hehe}\\The Author}
\institute[Inst.]{The Institute}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[timeinterval=60]{tdclock} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\initclock 
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\date{\tdhours : \tdminutes \ \ --- \cronominutes \ ' from start} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,yshift=2pt] at (current page.north east){\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{hehe}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
Now the logo is visible
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\framesubtitle{A}
Now the logo is visible
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should be able to adapt my answer for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301173/how-to-change-colour-of-navigation-bar-in-beamer looking at, and modifying the values of, `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemebeaver.sty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors for the `beaver` theme are set in `beamercolorthemebeaver.sty`, and are mostly based on `\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}`. You can replace all occurrences of `darkred` with, for example, `myblue`, and define `myblue` as `\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{00a1e5}` to get the desired result.

It's probably better to place the color definitions in a separate file called `beamercolorthememyblue.sty` and replace `\usecolortheme{beaver}` with `\usecolortheme{myblue}`. I've basically done that in the following code using `filecontents`. I also replaced your file `haha` with an example image so that it can be compiled.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{filecontents}{beamercolorthememyblue.sty}
\mode<presentation>

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{00a1e5}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=myblue!80!gray}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=myblue!60!black,bg=gray!30!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=myblue!70!black,bg=gray!15!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myblue!80!black,fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=myblue,bg=gray!5!white}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{fg=myblue,bg=gray!15!white}

\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{fg=myblue!10!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{fg=myblue!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=gray!10!white}

%\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=gray!60!white}

\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

\mode
<all>
\end{filecontents}

\usecolortheme{myblue}

\usepackage{tikz}
\title{The title}
\author[The author]{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{example-image}\\The Author}
\institute[Inst.]{The Institute}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[timeinterval=60]{tdclock} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\initclock 
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\date{\tdhours : \tdminutes \ \ --- \cronominutes \ ' from start} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,yshift=2pt] at (current page.north east){\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
Now the logo is visible
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\framesubtitle{A}
Now the logo is visible
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]